# Why an existing object from JSON shows the error "No value for"

Tags: java, json, android-studio

I'm developing a blog reader from Blogger using JSON in Android Studio. I have no problem getting the articles information, but if I try to get the nextPageToken it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
    private void parseJSON(String url) {
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            String answer = response.getString("nextPageToken");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            nextPageStr = "";

                        }

                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("items");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(request);

    }
```

I have also tried with JSONObject instead of String, with:  JSONObject nextPageTokenObject = response.getJSONObject("nextPageToken");

And also other option I used was using an if statement inside the second Try where I get the rest of the information:

```
if (response.has("nextPageToken")){
                                System.out.println("Got next page!!");
                               String nextPageToken = response.getString("nextPageToken");
                            }
```

The error I'm getting is:

> W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for nextPageToken
>
> W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:392)

The JSON code has a vale for nextPageToken:

```
{
 "kind": "blogger#postList",
 "nextPageToken": "CgkIChiA8pj-0ywQ1_iv0tag1pUS",
 "items": [
  {"url": "http...",
   "title": "some",
   "content": "some"

 (I erased this info because it was to long but all the info in items is working properly)
  }
 ]
}
```

So I have tried with those 3 options but the error is the same, why does it says is empty?, How can I get the information from nextPageToken?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you reduce your code further to show exactly what you are trying to do? The commented code also makes it confusing. I'm not sure which code you are running that causes the error.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Done it, thanks. The code with the error is the first Try for the nextPageToken

Comment: I suggest you print out the available keys in the `response` object.

Comment: Thanks @Code-Apprentice done it, and there is the problem, the available keys are just: I/System.out: ["kind","items"], but in the JSON the is the nextPageToken (as shown in the question), what can cause this problem?

Comment: The JSON object doesn't appear to have a key named "nextPageToken". Why do you think that it should? Are you referencing some documentation for the Blogger API?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks a lot for your help, I was indeed referencing documentation from the API and in the example it worked with the simple URL, but I found that for a real blog I need to explicitly ask for the nextPageToken adding "fields=nextPageToken" Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: can you show the solution code which is working? I cant figure it out and having same problem.